# Why Does My Discord.py Kick Command have a problem recognizing nicknames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command( )
async def kick(ctx, user_name: discord.User, reason):
    await ctx.guild.kick(user_name)
    await ctx.send(f"""{user_name} has been kicked for {reason}""")
```

For some reason, sometimes my bot is unable to recognize some nicknames. For nicknames without spaces/just one word, the bot has no problem kicking them. But for nicknames with underscores or spaces, it just doesn't work. Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your command:

- If you write a sentence after `user_name`, `reason` will only take the first word of this sentence as a value. To solve this first problem:

  ```
  #Change
  async def kick(ctx, user_name: discord.User, reason):

  #To
  async def kick(ctx, user_name: discord.User, *, reason):
  ```
- Then, `user_name` should be a [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) object, not a [`User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User) object. This way, your program will only look for the specified user in the server where the command was invoked:

  ```
  #Change
  async def kick(ctx, user_name: discord.User, *, reason):

  #To
  async def kick(ctx, user_name: discord.Member, *, reason):
  ```
- Finally, for it to work as intented, mention the user you want to kick instead of writing his name:
  Right way → `!kick @User You didn't respect the rules`
  No so right way → `!kick User You didn't respect the rules`

Comment: You are my savior, thank you for teaching me, I really appreciate it. How did you become so smart senpai? Did you study the documents?

Comment: I've been working a lot on my discord bot so I know a lot about the discod.py library. Reading other questions and the documentation helps a lot too.